# How to hide <h1> Title?

Tags: html, hide

I believe this is the code I want to hide on the front static page.   Is there a css code I can use to hide this?  I can just remove the "title" from the page, and that gets rid of it, BUT then the Link is gone from the Nave Menu.

```
<h1 class='page-title entry-title'>The Forum</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS's `display` :

```
<h1 style='display: none;' class='page-title entry-title'>The Forum</h1>
```

Creating a class `hidden` with `display: none;` as a property would be nice (requires you to edit CSS instead of HTML).

By the way, even though we are all happy to welcome newcomers, Stack sites have some rules about questions. One of them is that *your question must demonstrate minimal efforts in trying to solve your problems on your own*. A simple Google search could have solved that one for you.

*Edit:* If you can't edit the HTML/CSS code, inject Javascript .

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");

// Hide all H1s:
for(var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) 
    all[i].style.display = "none";

/*
 * Hide first H1:
 * Change the index to manipulate the 1st, 2nd, ... nth element.
 */
all[0].style.display = "none";
```

If you have no way to identify your `h1`, then you can't manipulate it.

*Edit 2:* New versions of CSS will allow you [designate the first](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/) `h1` on page:

```
h1:first-of-type{ display: none; }
```

Comment: I cannot edit the <h1> code. 

Is there a way I can do it using

#page title entry tile 
display: none;

Comment: Then edit the CSS code or inject JS. If you can't distinguish your `h1` from the others, then you can't touch it.

Comment: Or he can check how many h1 tags are before thats specific and put if statement in while loop to change just this one

Comment: @Aleksandar I added code about manipulating the first tag, he can just change the index if necessary, thanks ;) Thing is, if those `h1` are dynamically loaded, counting them might get tricky.

Comment: @user3808918 We can help you if you give us some code to see number of `h1` tags before this one you want to change. In that way, you'll get working code. Also, look at my solution, if some browser doesent support javascript, your `h1` tag will be visible. First try with css, than with javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you can't edit `<h1>`, do something like:

```
header>nav>ul>li>h1 {
 display: none;
}
```

Be sure to include right path, this is just demo.